# lattice, merge stripes

Tags: r, lattice

I´m building a lattice graph with the following code

```
table.df<-means 
library(lattice)
library(gridExtra)
graph1<-barchart(value1~Var1|Var2+Var3,data=table.df, ylab=NULL)
graph2<-barchart(value2~Var1|Var2+Var3,data=table.df, ylab=NULL)
grid.arrange(graph1,graph2, nrow=2, ncol=2)
```

I´m trying to merge the comum strips. For example the first strip from the first graph would be merge into a unique strip (normalVar3).

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why do you continue to post plots that are necessarily half whitespace?

Comment: You are right DWin. My apologies.I have edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `latticeExtra::useOuterStrips`